# How to make an image small in the body?

Tags: support, images

Suppose I inserted this image:

[image]

Is there a way to make this image smaller by using LaTeX code?

Comment: Related: [Rescaling images after posting](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10715/rescaling-images-after-posting). (I would even dare to say that the two post can be considered duplicate. Although I am not sure which of them should be closed as a duplicate target. Or would it be better to merge the two questions?)

Comment: Merging seems better to me @MartinSleziak.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following syntax (where the height is in pixels, you can of course customize it):

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfpSm.png" height="123">
```

to get:

[image]

You can also change the width, or both the height and the width (if you don't mind changing the aspect ratio):

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfpSm.png" width="100" height="200">
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Imgur automatically creates several different sized for images, you can get them by appending `s`, `t`, `m` or `l` to the filename (before the extension).

See the following examples:

```
![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfpSms.png)
```

[image]

```
![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfpSmt.png)
```

[image]

```
![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfpSmm.png)
```

[image]

```
![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfpSml.png)
```

[image]