# Compiling asymptote code for a figure in Math Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, mathjax, images

I wanted to ask a question in Mathematics Stack Exchange. In the question, I wanted to add a geometric figure. I have the asymptote code of the figure. I know I can compile the code in other sites and then take a screenshot to add the image. But I want to know if I can compile the code in math stack exchange. I added the code inside `$$` and `[asy][/asy]` but that didn't work.

(I thought this question belonged to the TeX Stack Exchange and asked it [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/612089/adding-asymptote-codes-in-math-stack-exchange) (now deleted). But the users there suggested asking it here.)

Comment: A possible duplicate - [Creating diagrams](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9632/876009)

Comment: @JitendraSingh Please note that the question isn't asked to find sites or softwares for creating digrams. Rather it asks whether one can compile asymptotes in Math SE. Using the word *related* will be much more meaningful than using *duplicate* in this case.

Comment: My **guess** is that the same issue would arise for other popular latex-graphics packages, such as PSTricks or PGF-Tikz.  I strongly suspect the issue is that you have to have specific rendering packages in the preamble to your latex document in order for the corresponding latex graphics package to be invoked.  mathSE maintainers (or Stack Exchange maintainers in general) must balance the effort needed to allow (for example) Asymptote/PSTricks/PgF-Tikz invocations against what it would gain.  ...see next comment

Comment: Conversion of an image into (for example) a png or jpeg file is routine. Also, uploading an image and inserting into a document is routine, as discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33909/recommendation-enhance-the-mathse-html-markdown-help-article-re-images), so image management doesn't seem to be an issue at mathSE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not possible. What we use here for mathematical typesetting is MathJax, which does not have that possibility.

I suggest that you take a look at [this question about creating diagrams](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9632/446262).