# How to draw Venn Diagrams in Math Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

How to draw Venn Diagrams in MSE using MathJax? Please help me out.

Comment: As far as I know. mathjax has no way to draw Venn diagrams.

Comment: Embedding images directly into a posted question is straightforward, assuming that you have a MathSE score of +10 or above.  If you have a camera or a scanner, then you can draw the image free hand on scratch paper, and then convert it into (for example) a *.jpg file.  Alternatively, you can consult [this article on graphic software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_information_graphics_software) to create the image directly on your PC.  ...see next comment

Comment: Another alternative is [Latex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) + (for example) one of [PSTricks or Asymptote or PGF-Tikz], as discussed in [this Latex forum](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).  Once the image (e.g. *.jpg file) is created, for help embedding the image into your posted question, see the Images section, at the bottom of 
[this article](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) 
and see also [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33909/recommendation-enhance-the-mathse-html-markdown-help-article-re-images).